# Is it possible to bind the null placeholder in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have a table where certain cells will be nil until the user fills them in, but I was hoping that I could change the null place-holder (i.e. the value it displays when the particular value for that cell is `nil`) depending on other parts of the application the user has already filled in or configured. Sort of like an auto-complete but not quite.

Is it possible to bind the null place-holder value or will I have to emulate this behaviour manually?

*Edit:*
To clarify, I'm looking for a solution to have distinct place-holder values for individual cells, not a single place-holder value to apply to the entire table or entire table column.

Comment: Do you mean for every cell a different placeholder or for the whole table?

Comment: I'm sure I've seen how to do this for a table (and it was really simple), I just can't remember. Aaargh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placeholder value is [passed as part of the options dictionary](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/Concepts/BindingsOptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002304-203776) when a binding is created.  Since a value in a dictionary is not something that can be bound, I don't think there's any "automatic" way to do this.